# How I can repeat the simulation of a code in Matlab automatically?

Tags: matlab

I have a code in Matlab , I want to run it 10 times but automatically without pressing the run button .
Is such thing possible in Matlab ? If yes, I want to save the output of each run so i would have 10 outputs for the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm agree with Benoit_11's idea, but because you asked about the "Run" button, i guess this is a *script* and not a *function*. If so, for running it 10 times you just need to type the name of the script (the .m file) inside a loop:

```
for i=1:10
Script_Name
end
```

If you want also save the outputs of each run, you can define it inside the loop, but it's depends on what exactly the output of your script.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you might want to do something like this:

1) Write your function and assign an output, according to some parameters:

```
function z = RepeatFct(x,y)

z = x*y;

end
```

2) Then you can run  this function in a script with a for-loop for example, storing each output (z in this case) along the way:

```
IterNum = 10;

Output = zeros(1,IterNum); % Pre-allocate memory for output.
for k = 1:IterNum

   %Add your code to generate representative input parameters.
    Output(k) = RepeatFct(k,rand*k);

end
```

I hope that's what you had in mind! If not please add some details to your question with maybe sample code.